# Looking for a function $f:[0, 1] \longrightarrow [0, +\infty]$ with the following properties

Tags: calculus

Strong desiderata (ie. should-have's):

1. $f$ is a composition of elementary functions
2. Such a composition is not too long
3. $f$ is not too expensive to compute/approximate
4. $f$ is $C^1$ (at least) almost everywhere (piecewise functions are valid, but the "pieces" should be few)
5. $f(1)$ is close to $+\infty$
6. $f(0)$ is close to 0
7. $f$ changes very fast near $1$
8. $f$ changes slowly near $0$

Weak desiderata (ie. nice-to-have's):

1. $f$ is $C^\infty$ (at least) almost everywhere

So far I've come up with stuff like the following, but I'd like to see what other people have to say.

1. $-\dfrac{1}{x-1} - 1$
2. $-$ln$(x-1)$
3. csc$\left(\dfrac{\pi(x+1)}{2}\right) - 1$
4. $\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{(1-x)(x+1)}} - 1$

Comment: Without context or tighter criteria this is more like a fishing trip than a question that can be answered.

Comment: @copper.hat I understand, but I'm having trouble coming up with tighter criteria... :(

Comment: How about $\tan\left( \frac{\pi}{2} x \right)$? Too similar to your $csc$ example?

Comment: @Bachmaninoff Yup, $tan$ is a quotient of $sin$ functions, and I've already accounted for such a "family". But that's precisely the type of suggestion I'm hoping to get!